# IIS 8.0 - ApplicationpoolIdentity account security permissions

Tags: iis-8

I am running my ASP.NET application in IIS 8.0 with the following settings,
* Anonymous Authentication (mapped to ApplicationPoolIdentity)
* Application Pool's Identity mapped to "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

My understanding is, it will create an account named "IIS Apppool\" and the worker process will run in that account.

My Question is,
* What permissions will the "IIS Apppool\" account have.
* My application is trying to write some logs outside the application folder, still the logs are getting written. Under what permissions these logs are getting written outside application\website's folder?
* Is this a security issue?
* How to restrict "IIS Apppool\" permissions only to application folder?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Answers are inline.

> What permissions will the `IIS Apppool\` account have.

The default permissions are described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981949). 
More you can read [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

> My application is trying to write some logs outside the application folder, still the logs are getting written. Under what permissions these logs are getting written outside application\website's folder?

This depends on a lot of factors. By default the application pool identity will be used. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649264.aspx) article to determine what identity will be used.

> Is this a security issue?

No this is not a security issue.

> How to restrict "IIS Apppool\" permissions only to application folder?

You actually need to do it the other way around. you need to restrict the access for IIS AppPool on other folders. One way would be to use Group Policy